# C# subtract list from number in all possible ways so the resultant number is bigger than 0

Tags: c#, list, subtraction

I need to subtract list from a number, so the resultant number will be equal or bigger than 0 with a smallest result possible. Also I need to see which items of the list were subtracted.

```
int a = 10;
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

I've tried this (probably really bad idea):

```
for (int c = 0; c < list.Count; c++)
{
    if (a > 0)
    {
        a = a - list.ElementAt(c);

        if (a < 0)
        {
            a = a + list.ElementAt(c);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", list.ElementAt(c));
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it only subtract in one way and doesn't find the best option.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: can you provide an example ?

Comment: You mean you want to retrieve a subset of a list such that its sum is as large as possible, while not being larger than the given number?

Comment: I think the OP wants the minimum result possible after subtracting each list item from given value, the result should be greater than or equal to 0

Comment: So for example, if the list has `{13, 12, 11, 9}` and the number given is `10`  then the result should be `1`.

Comment: @Habib number given is a

Comment: Off topic: It's probably better to use `list[c]` than `list.ElementAt(c)`.  That's because `.ElementAt()` is a linq method defined for `IEnumerable<T>`.  Using the built-in list indexer will be more efficient.  And it's a much more common well-known way of using lists.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, I meant `a` in code, which is equal to `10`

Comment: @Habib not sure how the answer should be 1 in that case

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, it is just my guess, but subtract given number from each list item, the result should be `3, 2, 1, -1` for the list of items, now since out of that result only positive or 0 is acceptable, then the result selected would be `1`.

Comment: sounds like a variation of the 0-1 knapsack problem...knapsack capacity is `a`,  the list of integers are the items, and we are picking set of items trying to maximize the weight without violating max capacity

Comment: I hope this will serve as example: I have a number a = 10 and list of numbers (2,4,3,6), so the best way is to subtract 6 and 4, so the result will be 0. But in my code it will subtract 2, 4 and 3 with a result 1. I need the program to choose the way with the smallest result possible.

Comment: you will need a more sophisticated solution than the one you developed.
This is basically a Subset sum problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP is looking to find smallest possible result after subtraction, but that result has to be greater than or equal to zero.

For example, in case of `{13, 12, 11, 9}` and the given number being `10` the result after subtraction should be `{3,2,1,-1}` for each list item respectively, in that case the final result should be `1` as it is minimum value, but greater than or equal to zero.

In that case the code could look like:

```
int a = 10;
List<int> list = new List<int> {13, 12, 11, 9};


int min = -1;
for (int c = 0; c < list.Count; c++)
{
    int tempResult = list[c] - a;
    if (tempResult >= 0)
    {
        min = tempResult;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(min);
```